# MySQL rewrite string in query on LIKE?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to following Query:

```
SELECT *, sites.id AS id, sites.url AS url, COUNT(sites_links.id) AS netwerklinks 
  FROM sites 
  LEFT JOIN data ON sites.id=data.id
  LEFT JOIN sites_links ON sites_links.naar LIKE CONCAT('%', sites.url ,'%')
 WHERE sites.url IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY sites.id
```

the "sites.url" is like = https://www.domainhere.nl
And joining them with http://www.domainhere.nl (notice the HTTP).

I would like to join if it's either "HTTP://" or "HTTPS://".

I though of rewrite in the query, so if the sites.url gets rewritten to http:// it all should be good. But can't find how to do that and if it's possible? Hope stack can help me out!

Comment: Nothing that begins `SELECT *` and includes `GROUP BY` is ever going to end well. See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Use `REPLACE()` on both `sites_links.naar` and `sites.url`:

```
ON replace(sites_links.naar, 'https://', 'http://') 
   LIKE 
   CONCAT('%', replace(sites.url, 'https://', 'http://') ,'%')
```